# How to align div to center of verital and horizontal

Tags: html, css

I want align the div to center.

like this

[image]

I have tried margin-top, vertical-align

but they also not work.

I also set the left less than 0px

but the inner div still a 0px of left

If I want the div as above image

how to modify css to make it as above image?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div
{
    border:solid;
}
#outer
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
}
#inner
{
    background:white;
    height:20%;
    width:120%;
    left:-10px;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-buttom:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">abc</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/vn6Wx/

```
#inner
{
    background:white;
    height:40%;
    width:200%;
    position: relative;
    left:-50%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-buttom:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only flexible way to vertically align an element without using JavaScript is by putting it in a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

http://jsfiddle.net/dmvcs/

```
#outer{
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:50px;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  border:2px solid red;
}

#inner{
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-25px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border:2px solid green;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            html { height:100%; width:100%; }
            body { background-color: yellow; margin:0; padding:0; }
            #outer { width:100%; min-height:100%; background-color:red; position:absolute; }
            #inner { width:500px; height:500px; background-color:blue; position:relative; margin:10% auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!